# Dynamically changing the scale of an A-frame entity (GLTF model) from microphone input

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to use frequency data from a microphone to dynamically alter the scale and/or position of a GLTF model in A-Frame. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('voicecontrol', {
    init: function () {
      console.log("voicecontrol called");

    },
    tick: function (time, timeDelta) {
      // get scene
      var sceneEl = this.el;  // Or this.el since we're in a component.
      // get model
      var mandalaEl = sceneEl.querySelector('#interactiveMandala');
      // get current frequency
      var currentFreq = freqAvg();
      var positionChange = ((currentFreq/16) + 1 );
      //console.log("position change factor " + positionChange);
      mandalaEl.setAttribute('animation', 'to', {x:positionChange, y:0, z:positionChange});
      console.log(mandalaEl.getAttribute('animation', 'to'));
    }
  });

</script>
```

And:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs voicecontrol>
```

...

```
<a-marker type='pattern' url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DaveyDangerpants/youarehere/master/images/pattern-marker.patt'>
<a-entity rotation="90 0 0">
  <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale=".1 .1 .1" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 0 360; loop: true; easing:linear; dur: 45000;">
    <a-entity id="interactiveMandala" gltf-model="#mandala" scale="0.15 0.15 0.15" position="0 0 0"
        animation="property: position; to:0 0 0; dur: 100;">
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

I can see the microphone data streaming in and console seems to be indicating that I'm setting the animation component's 'to' values correctly, but the model isn't moving. Is this an AR.JS issue? I've never made anything with A-Frame or AR.js, so I'm a bit lost. Help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't use the `animation` component. Each time the frequency changes (actually on each frame rendered) you shouldn't restart the animation to a new value.

---

I'd move the model along one of the axis, depending on the frequency. Let's say the range is 300 - 3000 Hz, so if i want to move the model tops 1 meter I'd do:

```
tick: function() {
  let pos = this.el.getAttribute("position")
  var currentFreq // however you get the frequency
  pos.x = currentFreq / 3000
  this.el.setAttribute("position", pos)
}
```

now, on each frame, the position will be set depending on the frequency values.

---

To make the animation work, you'd have to set up a begin event

```
animation="......;startEvents: start"
```

and then emit the event
    this.el.emit("start")

But as i said, i think its a bad idea.